# Why is Chinese font “more square” on desktop and how to solve it?

Tags: html, css, fonts, padding, cjk

I'm developing a Chinese language cards game.

```css
.cards {
    display:flex;
    justify-content:space-evenly;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
    font-size:2em;
}
.card {
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;
    border:1px solid black;
    margin:0.25em;
    padding:0.25em;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.red {
    color:red;
    border:1px solid red;
    padding:0;
}
.blue {
    color:blue;
    border:1px solid blue;
    padding:0;
}
```

```html
<div class='cards'>
  <div class='card'>
    <div class='red'>对</div>
    <div class='blue'>對</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Below is a print-screen on desktop (Firefox 78.11.0esr 64-bit on Debian Buster). The area inside the red rectangles (CSS `border:1px solid red; padding:0;`, same below) is 38x49 pixels (0.78:1 ratio).

[image: shorter red rectangle]

Below is a print-screen on desktop (Chromium 90.0.4430.212 on Debian Buster). The area inside the red rectangles is 32x44 pixels (0.73:1 ratio).

[image: medium red rectangle]

Below is a print-screen on smartphone (Chrome 91.0.4472.88 on Android 9/MIUI Global 11.0.4). The area inside the red rectangles is 64x94 pixels (0.68:1 ratio).

[image: taller red rectangle]

Why are the ratios so different? It may seem a small difference, but the dead space above and below characters on the smartphone is taking a lot of screen space.

I don't want to [specify a @font-face](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9341142/1086511), because of the large size of the files. I could use negative vertical margins, but that's dangerous if I don't know the ratio beforehand. Is there any other way to impose square characters for Chinese fonts (since Chinese characters are square by design)?

Comment: Yes, fonts are different on different devices.

Comment: Have you tried changing the `line-height` property?

Comment: @MrLister On point! Thank you!

Comment: Also, you haven't specified any fonts in the CSS, so the browser/webview is 100% allowed to pick whatever font it feels would work best. Which means it can be a _completely different font_ from what you want. Specify the font stack you need, and ideally use a (subset) webfont so you can _guarantee_ your content always looks the same, no matter what loads it.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Loading a regular Chinese font would be heavy, creating a subset would be arduous, and any webfont (like Google's) could change tomorrow, so I choose to stick to the browser default. I don't need it to look exactly the same, I just expected square characters because that's a rule for Chinese language. But Mr Lister comment solved the issue for me. Thank you anyway!

Comment: why would it be arduous? turn into a chunked WOFF2 and done: you can spread one font over 100 files that only get loaded as needed based on what unicode points are used on your page(s). (although of course realistically you'd turn it into maybe 10ish)

Comment: But even then: at the very least show the CSS `font-family` stack, because windows, macos, linuax, and android all use _completely_ different default fonts.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I remember seeing this once and didn't think it was trivial. But even if it is, I have a list with about 20 thousand Chinese sentences, some of which appear onscreen depending on the characters studied. So yes, I don't think it will be trivial to create subsets. And it's working as I expected now, so why bother? Anyway, I may need to create such subsets for other purposes, so thanks for the hint.

Comment: Fair enough. Should you want to take another stab at "decent WOFF2 for my content", you might find https://github.com/aui/font-spider useful.

Comment: Maybe not quite related: Always use `lang` attribute when possible. For example, `<div class='red' lang='zh-Hans'>对</div><div class='blue' lang='zh-Hant'>對</div>`. So browsers may pick correct font. As same character may have different render under different standard (Hans, Hant). If you are creating your own font, you may also be noticed that same font may not work for both simplified and traditional scripts, as different locale have different writing standard.